# Spring Boot Security Multi Http with OAuth not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I had a working Rest API developed with Spring Boot and protected with Sprint Security and OAuth:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableOAuth2Client
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().antMatcher("/**").csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

}
```

Then I added some web forms to my app so I extended the security configuration to handle multiple HttpSecurity following this instructions: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity and it didn't work anymore.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    @EnableOAuth2Client
    @Order(1)                                    
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    @EnableOAuth2Client
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    }
}
```

When comparing the log files with the working version I found that the 
OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter is not fired on the Multy HTTP configuration:

Working log

```
12:45:01.808 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/external_users' matched by universal pattern '/**'
12:45:01.809 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /external_users at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
12:45:01.810 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /external_users at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
12:45:01.812 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /external_users at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
12:45:02.093 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /external_users at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
12:45:02.093 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /external_users at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
12:45:02.093 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/external_users'; against '/logout'
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /external_users' doesn't match 'POST /logout
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /external_users' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /external_users' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
12:45:02.094 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /external_users at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
```

Non working log

```
12:49:42.506 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/external_users'; against '/api/**'
12:49:42.510 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/external_users at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
12:49:42.511 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/external_users at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
12:49:42.512 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/external_users at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
12:49:42.514 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/external_users at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
12:49:42.515 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/external_users at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
12:49:42.515 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
12:49:42.517 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/external_users'; against '/logout'
12:49:42.518 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
12:49:42.518 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /api/external_users' doesn't match 'POST /logout
12:49:42.518 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
12:49:42.518 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /api/external_users' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
12:49:42.518 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
12:49:42.518 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /api/external_users' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
12:49:42.518 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
12:49:42.519 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/external_users at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative configuration that worked for me:

1. Change the first annotation for @EnableResourceServer instead of @ EnableWebSecurity
2. Change to ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter the parent class for ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter
3. Remove the Order annotation for FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

This is the final working code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    @EnableOAuth2Client
    @Order(1)                                    
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    @EnableOAuth2Client
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    }
}
```